# Not able to reference ((MainActivity) getApplication()).getTracker(MainActivity.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics in my application and following a tutorial from [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api) Everything is setup:

I have a MainActivity which extends Activity and has three Tab Fragments attached, I initialize the code in this Activity like:

```
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxx";

    //Logging TAG
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, 
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, 
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public MainActivity() {
        super();
    }

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                            : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
                    mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
```

Now in one of the Tabs I am trying to do:

```
((MainActivity) getApplication()).getTracker(MainActivity.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

However I get the following:

Cannot cast from Application to MainActivity in the above line of code. Any hints? The fragment I am trying to use it in has the following signature:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling this inside the fragment, perhaps you need to call getActivity instead?

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getTracker(MainActivity.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```